# Destroy component by *ngIf in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular5, I am conditionally removing/adding a component from/in dom. My expectation is - when I remove the component, it's ngOnDestroy() method should be called. But it is not happening in my case.

Is my expectation wrong?

How can I achieve the behavior i.e. destroying a component while removing/hiding from dom?

Comment: can you show us the code u tried?